# 401 - Unauthorized Signature Invalid Intuit Partner Platform

Tags: oauth, quickbooks

When implementing OAuth in Intuit Anywhere, I get 401 Unauthorized (Signature Invalid) error while requesting request token.

I am sure that I have implemented my signature part correctly. I verified it with the result of an available tool as well.

I have included oauth_callback also in my signature generation apart from other oauth_* parameters.

Intuit Anywhere asks for certain URLs like application URL, disconnect URL, manage users URL. What is the significance of these URLs?

I am trying to develop a non ui application which would consume IPP's data services.

Answer (score 3):

Lalit, there's documentation on those fields you are asking about [here](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0030_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Create_New_App#Application_Settings).

On the OAuth request part, if you update your question with an example of your query parameters and signature I may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Lalit,

A couple of avenues through which you could reach out to the Intuit team -

Post questions and read feedback in our developer Support Forums -
https://idnforums.intuit.com/

Submit IPP Developer Relations Support request -
https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0100_Support/0010_Submit_Support_Incidents